# Output index and element using range

Tags: python, python-2.7

how to fix this
Expected output:

```
1 - that
2 - is
3 - weird
```

The code:

```
list = ['that', 'is', 'weird']
for i, k in range(list):
     print str(i) + ' - ' + k
```

Comment: Why did you think `range(list)` would give you an iterable of pairs `i, k`? Were you thinking of `enumerate`?

Comment: It'd be useful for you to provide / read the traceback this code generates

Answer (score 0):

Try enumerate instead of range:

```
words = ['that', 'is', 'weird']
for i, k in enumerate(words):
     print str(i) + ' - ' + k
```

Comment: Or, if you want to be even more pythonic: 

    `print '\n'.join([(str(i) + ' - ' + k) for i, k in enumerate(words)])  `